# Разработка приложения на Framework7 Vue

Tags: javascript, framework7

Столкнулся с проблемами при разработке на Framework7 Vue, примеры из официальной документации у меня просто не работают.

Вот пример:

```
Vue.use(Framework7Vue, Framework7);

const rootNode = "main";

new Vue({
  el: rootNode,
  template: '<vue-app/>',
  components: {
    "vue-app": App
  },

  framework7: {
    root: rootNode,
    /* Uncomment to enable Material theme: */
    // material: true,
    routes: Routes
  },
  methods: {
    onF7Ready(f7) {
      console.log("onF7Ready");
      console.log(this);
      // do some f7 related logic
      f7.dialog.alert('App initialized');
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.dir(this);
    });


  }
});
```

Вот что получаю я в консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить this не содержит описаных в документации

```
this.$f7
this.$$
this.Dom7
this.$device
this.$request
this.$utils
this.$theme
```

Также `onF7Ready` метод не был вызван. при этом само по себе приложение запустилось и роутинг по ссылкам отрабатывает нормально.

[Ссылка на конкретный раздел документации по framework7 vue](https://framework7.io/vue/vue-component-extensions.html#context-extensions)

Я так понимаю текущая версия документации не совпадает с версией фреймворка. Если так, возможно ге-то есть актуальная информация или может кто-то сможет подсказать как на н]м сейчас разрабатывать ?

Или же возможно я делаю что-то не так, кто-то увидит ошибку и скажет что делать ?

Или может кто-то предложит замену (не обязательно на vue)